# how to retrieve multiple phone number from one contact in android

Tags: android, android-manifest

**Here is my code**

```
if(Integer.parseInt(hasPhoneNumber) > 0)
{
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    Uri myPhoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, contactId);

    // Query the table
    Cursor phoneCursor = managedQuery(
            myPhoneUri, null, null, null, null);

    // Get the phone numbers from the contact
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor1 = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
        String contactId1 = cursor1.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        //  Get all phone numbers.
        Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId1, null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Phone  =  " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        phones.close();
    }
}
```

It is fetching only one phone number at a time from one contact. I need to retrieve multiple numbers like TYPE_HOME ,TYPE_MOBILE, TYPE_WORK simultaneously which is saved in one contact, how can I do this?

Comment: for you info, the same code we are using for fetch different phone numbers of one contact. And not me all the other who want this.

Comment: my need is to fetch multiple numbers like TYPE_HOME, TYPE_MOBILE, TYPE_WORK simultaneously in one contacts at a time.

Comment: For this you have to iterate one by one phone numbers with different types, because all types have a different uri for query thats why you get one by one phone number.

Comment: how?? can you send some sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one its work for me.

```
  String [] cname;
int cnt=0;
boolean [] checkall;
String number1="";
String num="";

String nameofuser=ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC";

Cursor phones =getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, nameofuser);
    cname=new String[phones.getCount()];
    checkall=new boolean[phones.getCount()];
    while(phones.moveToNext())
    {

        String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String number=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        String emailid=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));


        Cursor phone1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (phone1.moveToFirst()) 
        {

           do
           {

               number1=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
               int type=phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));

               Log.d("before switch", ""+number1 );

               if(num.contains(number))
               {
                           switch (type)
                           {
                               case Phone.TYPE_HOME:

                                   num+="\nHOME:"+number1;
                                   break;

                               case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:

                                   num+="\nMOBILE:"+number1;
                                   break;


                               case Phone.TYPE_WORK:

                                   num+="\nWORK:"+number1;
                                   break;

                               default:
                                   break;
                           }

               }  
           }while(phone1.moveToNext());

         }

          //  phones.close(); 

        Cursor emailCur = getContentResolver().query( 
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, 
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                new String[]{emailid}, null); 
        emailCur.moveToFirst();
        String email = emailCur.getString(
                emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

        cname[cnt]=name+"\n"+number1+"\n"+email+num;
        checkall[cnt]=true;
        cnt++;
        num="";
        //Toast.makeText(DisplaycontectActivity.this, "\nname=\t"+ name+ "\nnum=\t"+ number+"\nmail_id\t"+email, 1).show();

    }

    phones.close();
    AlertDialog.Builder ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplaycontectActivity.this);
    ad.setTitle("contact list");
    ad.setMultiChoiceItems(cname, checkall, new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
 AlertDialog adb=ad.create();
adb.show();

 }}
```

This will display all the contact detail stored in your phone as well as display address,phone number and EMailid.

All contect displays in alert dialog box which is by default selected........try it...

Answer (score 0):

```
String id , name;
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

     String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

     Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,  null, null, null, sortOrder);



      if (cur.getCount() > 0) {


            while (cur.moveToNext()) {



                id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                name = cur.getString( cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Log.i(tag, "Id is "+ id+"\t Name is"+name);

            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0){                      


                        Cursor pCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,

                            null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);


// this second loop will retrieve all the contact numbers for a paricular contact id 
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {


                // Do something with phones



                       int phNumber = pCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                       String phn = pCur.getString(phNumber);

                       Log.i("phn number",  phn);



                    } 

                    pCur.close();

                }

                }

    }
```